# AjAX post request trouble redirecting the page

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to redirect to a different webpage on the success of an AJAX post request with express, but I can't figure it out.

I've tried using `res.redirect()` on the server side, and `window.location=url` and `location.href=url` and `location.replace(url)` on the client side, but none of these are working for me.

Here's my jQuery ajax request:

```
function addContact(){
  var contactName = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();

  var newContact = {name: contactName, email: email};

  $.post('/contacts/add', newContact)
    .success(function(data){
      location.href = data.redirect;
    })
}
```

And here's my server code:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
    fs.readFile('./contacts.json', function(err, data){
      if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);

      var contactArr = JSON.parse(data);
      var newContact = req.body;
      contactArr.push(newContact);

      fs.writeFile('./contacts.json', JSON.stringify(contactArr),     function(err){
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: well the server should be returning the url....

Answer (score 0):

The server code needs to send the new URL, rather than a redirect, and the client code then uses that URL to redirect. So:

server code:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
    fs.readFile('./contacts.json', function(err, data){
      if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
      var contactArr = JSON.parse(data);
      var newContact = req.body;
      contactArr.push(newContact);

      fs.writeFile('./contacts.json', JSON.stringify(contactArr), function(err){
          if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
          res.json({"redirect":"http:www.google.com"});//replace this with your redirect url
      });
    });
});
```

and client code:

```
function addContact(){
  var contactName = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var newContact = {name: contactName, email: email};

  $.post('/contacts/add', newContact)
    .success(function(data){
      window.location.href = data.redirect;
    })
}
```

should do it.